# How do I Index an element in an array of arrays in C#

Tags: arrays, indexing

So my question is simply,

given

`var myArray = new[]{new []{0, 0, 7, 0},
                     new []{0, 0, 0, 0},
                     new []{0, 0, 0, 0},
                     new []{0, 0, 0, 0}};`

how do I change the value that is 7 to 0?
i know to index a single array I would use myArray[2] = 0

I just dont know how to index a value in an array of arrays.
is it something like this, myArray[0[2]]?

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Very close. Think about the object `myArray[0]` returns - It's an array itself, yes?

And to access the 3rd element in the first list, we just do `myArray[0][2]`. Essentially, we are indexing the 2nd item in the first item of `myArray`